# Visual basic: How do you count the number of occurances of each letter in a sentence? (Count the amount of 'a' or 'f')

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing some code to identify the amount of letters in a textbox.

"Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone."

the code would identify that there is 7 "e" s and would do this for the whole alphabet. If mixed cased letters should be counted together (It would still count the 7 'e's despite one being uppercase). How would i do this?

Comment: Before you get the answer - is this some kind of homework assignment?

Comment: No its not homework. Its a personal project, its for a Ceaser cipher decoder I'm making for fun. Its going well so far but I'm stumped on finding and using some kind of count function

Comment: `string` is array of characters

Comment: I see 7 occurrences of the letter 'e', are you differentiating between upper (E) and lower (e) case?

Comment: I am not differentiating between upper and lower case.

Comment: Ok then, see my posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a console app demonstrating, how it can be done.
Notice it does not distinguish between lower and uppercase, nor non alphabetical symbols. It's a matter of filtering those out if needed.

```
Sub Main()

        ' declare variables and objects to use 
        Dim charCollection As Dictionary(Of Char, Int32) = New Dictionary(Of Char, Int32)()
        Dim paragraph As String = "Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone."

        ' iterate each character in paragraph and use each one as key in the dictionary list
        ' if letter exist increment value for that key else add new key
        For Each chr As Char In paragraph
            If charCollection.ContainsKey(chr) Then
                charCollection.Item(chr) = charCollection.Item(chr) + 1
            Else
                charCollection.Add(chr, 1)
            End If
        Next

        ' display interval of each character
        For Each chr As Char In charCollection.Keys
            Console.WriteLine($"the count of character {chr} is : {charCollection.Item(chr)}")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine($"Total of {charCollection.Keys.Count} different characters")

    End Sub
```

Output is :

```
the count of character E is : 1
the count of character v is : 2
the count of character e is : 6
the count of character r is : 1
the count of character y is : 2
the count of character o is : 5
the count of character n is : 3
the count of character   is : 9
the count of character w is : 2
the count of character a is : 2
the count of character s is : 3
the count of character b is : 1
the count of character u is : 1
the count of character , is : 1
the count of character I is : 1
the count of character t is : 3
the count of character h is : 1
the count of character m is : 1
the count of character i is : 1
the count of character l is : 1
the count of character . is : 1
Total of 21 different characters
```

EDIT: another version that accounts for lowercase and non digit/letter
EDIT 2: added: paragraph = paragraph.ToLower(), removed: lcChr = Char.ToLower(chr)

```
Sub Main()

' declare variables and objects to use 
Dim charCollection As Dictionary(Of Char, Int32) = New Dictionary(Of Char, Int32)()
Dim paragraph As String = "Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone."
Dim lcChr As Char

paragraph = paragraph.ToLower() 

' iterate each character in paragraph and use each one as key in the dictionary list
' if letter exist increment value for that key else add new key
For Each chr As Char In paragraph        
    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr) Then
        If charCollection.ContainsKey(chr) Then
            charCollection.Item(chr) = charCollection.Item(chr) + 1
        Else
            charCollection.Add(chr, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next

' display interval of each character
For Each chr As Char In charCollection.Keys
    Console.WriteLine($"the count of character {chr} is : {charCollection.Item(chr)}")
Next
Console.WriteLine($"Total of {charCollection.Keys.Count} different characters")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, alot. How would you write this so that mixed casing letters are counted together. So that ' the count of character e is : 7'

Comment: I'll make an edit to my answer, to accommodate lower/uppercase and also non digit letter

Comment: Or `Dim paragraph As String = "Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone.".TolLower`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ to shorten the code

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim myText As String = "Everyone was busy, so I went to the movie alone.".ToLower()

        'Get each character including space
        For Each c As Char In myText.Distinct
            'Count the occurrence of characters and write to the console
            Console.WriteLine(c & " occurs " & myText.Count(Function(d As Char) d = c) & " times")

        Next

End Sub
```